# How to avoid the security risk of exec()

Tags: python-3.x, exec, dynamic-variables

I'm doing a test web service project where I need to create some dynamic variables. To implement this, I have no option but using exec() function like follow.

```
    for parameter in parameter_names:
        if parameter["type"] == "number":
            exec("%s= %s(request.args.get('%s'))"%(parameter["name"],"float",parameter["name"]))
            para_collection[parameter["name"]] = eval(parameter["name"])
        else:
            exec("%s= %s(request.args.get('%s'))"%(parameter["name"],"str",parameter["name"]))
            para_collection[parameter["name"]] = eval(parameter["name"])
```

Here I accept values from a web call and assign them to dynamic variable names.Even though this code gives me the expected result, I have seen number of StackOverflow posts, mentioning security risks of exec() function. Therefore I would like to evaluate this code for security.

What scenarios I need to test ?
If not exec() what are the alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to validate that `parameter["name"]` is safe.  The best way to do this is to white list a set of values that are allowed to be provided by the user.  As is, there are all sorts of dangerous things an attacker can do to your code -- especially remote code execution.

Example: attacker sends in `import os\nos.system("rm -rf *") #` for `parameter["name"]` (assuming Linux OS but attack can be adapted for other OS).  Ouch, you lose a lot of data.

More generally, the current implementation allows the attacker to create a web shell or reverse shell that allows him to execute anything on your server as if he were local.

What is the format that your `parameter["name"]` can take?  If it is only alphanumeric, then validation can be a regex that checks whether the values match an alphanumeric pattern.  If not, return a 400 error to the user.  If valid, allow the command to proceed.

See guide: [Secure Coding: Understanding Input Validation](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2018/02/18/secure-coding-understanding-input-validation/).